# Test if webcam picks up infrared

Tags: software, camera, infrared

I know the good old-fashioned way of shining a remote at a camera to see if it picks up infrared, but I'd like to know if there's any code that does it for you. That'd be much more professional.

Comment: Badly automating something best done by hand just so you can claim it is more sophisticated is not being professional, it's being silly.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, you could argue that an automated process does not operator bias, which is more professional. I would agree with your statement, but I think anubis221 is still learning, a good answer with constructive feedback would be productive, but a downvote on an honest question where someone is trying to solve a technical issue may not be the best approach, and may even scare potential contributors away from our site.

Comment: @Kortuk it would be a lot of work to come up with an even remotely reliable algorithm for evalating IR sensitivity, but it's pretty easy to do a go/no-go as a human equipped with a TV remote. The only time it would really make sense to automate this would be in a factory test setting; otherwise simply getting some calibration to a manual process would be enough.  Nonetheless I _did not vote the question down_

Comment: @chris Stratton, I actually thought your comment's wording implied you did not vote it down. I am not trying to make you feel like you need to defend yourself. I thought your feedback was very good, I was just suggesting it be done in a way that seems less aggressive. I also thought it was worthy of an answer, but I can understand making it a comment. I do not disagree on the IR algorithm, on top of that, nicer cameras have algorithms implemented internally to filter IR because it is cheaper than a filter. I would suggest having a bright IR light to test for the filter.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, on that note, please forgive me if I seemed aggressive. I was only trying to help keep the community friendly. Good questions are not as important as good answers, and users, like yourself, make up those whom can make good answers.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way in software to determine if a webcam is sensitive to infrared, unless you have a separate computer controlled IR emitter which is visible to the camera.

The aspects of a webcam that determine it's infrared sensitivity are both hardware, and non-electronic, which renders them completely invisible from the computers perspective.

The only exception I can think of to this is a webcam which specifically advertises itself as being IR sensitive, in which case you could do an online lookup based off the VID and PID to find the model, and look at it's specifications.

To be specific, the optical component responsible for blocking IR is a [*hot mirror*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_mirror).

Fortunately, removing the hot mirror is very easy, and there are [many](http://tech.blorge.com/Structure%3a%20/2007/10/04/how-to-turn-your-webcam-into-an-ir-night-vision-camera/), [many](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Webcam-Into-an-Infrared-Camera), [many](http://www.instructables.com/id/Infrared-IR-Webcam/?ALLSTEPS), [many](http://www.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbw.cgi?Gw=webcam+ir) walkthroughs.

Comment: I didn't know making an IR camera was that easy. Of course, taking apart the (actual) digital camera I had was definitely more difficult than I had hoped due to extremely small screws and the hot mirror was made of glass and in a container which was soldered. I ended up having to just chip out the glass, so now there is some permanent dust and a small scratch in the pictures, but it works great and is very impressive. Thanks!

Comment: I've actually replaced the hot mirror with a hand-cut cold mirror (transmits *only* IR) in a very expensive camera (Nikon D80 SLR). It was an adventure. OTOH, it takes beautiful pictures.

Answer (score 1):

It likely has an infrared filter in the optical path so that it doesn't have to do expensive DSP. All you need to do is take it off. [Hackaday](http://hackaday.com/2005/03/14/make-an-infrared-webcam/) featured this, but [this](http://www.hoagieshouse.com/IR/) is a better guide.

Comment: The filter blocks the infra-red which would interfere with the image but still allows a considerable amount through, which is why you can see the IR light from a remote because it's bright enough to matter.

Comment: Why'd I get a downvote? I have the same answer as Fake Name.

Comment: #Thomas I've never been able to see a remote's IR light from any camera I've owned?

Comment: @earlz, I have never used a camera that filtered it. Darn cell phone cameras.