# IR LEDs for illumination, as used in night-vision cameras

Tags: led, infrared, camera

Being aware that IR LEDs come in various frequency-ranges, illumination intensities, sizes etc., was wondering if someone can help me identify the right type of IR LEDs, a cluster of which could potentially be used to illuminate a dark-room, s.t. I can use my standard web-cam to serve as a night-vision camera ?

Professional surveillance cameras seem to have things like "IR cut filters", which I believe are optical parts that are moved-in/out electro-mechanically, to help them work well, both in night and day. Do their optics (s.a., the lens, sensors) also have some differences, say compared to those found in commonly found webcams ?

Comment: Found an answer for the 2nd part of my question. [This link here](http://tech2.in.com/how-to/webcams/how-to-enable-night-vision-on-a-webcam/230132) answers it well.  So, what remains is to find the right kind of IR LEDs.

Comment: Uh, looks like even the first part is answered (popped up as 'RELATED' question). [Here's the answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7771/best-wavelength-for-ir-leds-to-be-used-with-a-hacked-up-ir-camera?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I found those on a more thorough search.

Part-1) Right kind of IR LED for the job. [This SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7771/best-wavelength-for-ir-leds-to-be-used-with-a-hacked-up-ir-camera?rq=1) has some answers.

Part-2) Difference (optics, sensor) between webcam and surveillance cams. [This external link](http://tech2.in.com/how-to/webcams/how-to-enable-night-vision-on-a-webcam/230132) has it explained quite well.